# Write Python List to file - works on friends computer but not mine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a program in which I need 3 arrays (lists) to write to a txt file. When I run the code on my computer, the txt file is empty. I sent it to a friend, who ran it and the program populated the txt file on his computer.

I have next to no experience coding and need the txt file for a homework assignment.

Note: It did run earlier today on my computer, although one of the arrays did not write to the file. However, when I ran it again later (after adding additional print statements earlier in the code for error checking), it again wasn't writing to the txt file.  What could cause this type of behavior? My code for writing to the txt file is as follows:

```
import csv
.....
MyFile = open('BattSim.txt', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(MyFile)
wr.writerow(RedArmy)
wr.writerow(BlueArmy)
wr.writerow(BattleTime)
MyFile.close
```

Comment: You have to *call* the close function:  `MyFile.close()`

Answer (score 2):

Did you run this in an interactive interpreter (or in a non-CPython interpreter or otherwise crash in some weird way)? If so, the problem is that you didn't actually `flush`/`close` the file; you referenced the `close` method without calling it. You wanted `MyFile.close()` (with parens to call).

Alternatively, you use a `with` statement to get guaranteed `close` behavior (even if an exception is thrown midway):

```
import csv
.....
# Use with statement to autoclose, and newline='' to follow csv module rules
with open('BattSim.txt', 'w', newline='') as MyFile:
    wr = csv.writer(MyFile)
    wr.writerow(RedArmy)
    wr.writerow(BlueArmy)
    wr.writerow(BattleTime)
```